# Google Sheets - Using countuniqueifs and IMPORTRANGE to work in two separete workbooks

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to count unique values (that match a condition) from workbook A into a Workbook B. In workbook A I've all my transactions with a column (Col1) with "customer Key (8 digit number)" and another column (Col12) with a serial number. One customer may have several serial numbers.

In workbook B I've the Clients List with a column (col1) "customer Key" and I want to count how many different serial numbers has each Client.

I've tried everithing I've founded on the web and with this formula I always get "1"

thanks in advance to anyone who could help me

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(query(IMPORTRANGE("url from workbook A";"Bajada Transacciones!$J:$U");"select unique(Col12) where Col1 = '"&A2&"' "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing that second 'unique':

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(query(IMPORTRANGE("url from workbook A";"Bajada Transacciones!$J:$U");"select Col12 where Col1 = '"&A2&"' "))
```

If it doesn't work try doing only the QUERY to see what it imports

Comment: Hi Martín, thanks for your answer. I got the same "1" in all cases without the second "unique", I don't understand the second part with the "QUERY" advice

Comment: See what does it show when you do: =query(IMPORTRANGE("url from workbook A";"Bajada Transacciones!$J:$U");"select Col12 where Col1 = '"&A2&"' ") - maybe you're getting an error

Comment: Or only the IMPORTRANGE part, maybe you haven't approved the link yet?

Comment: Hi Martín, It's still no working, If i quit the Countunique the result is an "#ERROR" "Result is too large".  I made sa sample of both workbooks the result in E9 on "Worbook B" should be "4" [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MD4CJCRnJ9rVEchi_k-TcaS7aNevMSJa?usp=sharing) Maybe you can understand better the problem. Thanks